# Agrupar e agregar dados

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho o seguinte arquivo em **CSV** (**12** Milhões de registros):

```
UF Municipio   Cod  NIS         Valor Data  
MA IMPERATRIZ  803  16361947271 45.00 01/01/2011  
MA IMPERATRIZ  803  74629273937 15.00 01/01/2011  
BA RUY BARBOSA 3845 16481166579 50.00 01/02/2011  
BA RUY BARBOSA 3845 16481166579 50.00 01/03/2011  
MG IPATINGA    653  73639474937 10.00 01/03/2011  
MG IPATINGA    653  83733638376 20.00 01/03/2011  
MG IPATINGA    653  52648747648 25.00 01/03/2011  
...
```

Preciso agrupar os dados por ***Data***, ***UF*** e ***Município***, calculando a quantidade de ***NIS*** e somando os valores. Ou seja, para cada grupo de ***Data***, ***UF*** e ***Município***, preciso contar a quantidade de ***NIS*** distintos e somar os valores. Para os dados acima, o resultado pretendido seria:

```
Data       UF Municipio   Quant. Valor  
01/01/2011 MA IMPERATRIZ  002    60.00  
01/02/2011 BA RUY BARBOSA 001    50.00  
01/03/2011 BA RUY BARBOSA 001    50.00  
01/03/2011 MG IPATINGA    003    55.00  
...
```

Este resultado deve gerar um novo arquivo **CSV**.
Para somar ou contar os valores eu uso os códigos abaixo (que funcionam):

```
Conta_NIS = csvPanda.groupby(['Data', 'UF', 'Municipio']).NIS.count()  
Soma_Valor = csvPanda.groupby(['Data', 'UF', 'Municipio']).Valor.sum()
```

Mas como incluir as duas agregações (`count` e `sum`) em uma mesma saída para exportar para um novo arquivo **CSV**?

Muito grato a todos!

Comment: serviria em awk ou perl?

Answer (score 3):

Consegui encontrar a solução usando o "groupby" do Pandas. Criei dois agrupamentos distintos, porém pelos mesmos campos, um por valor (soma da coluna Valor)  e outro com a contagem do número de NIS.

BF_Valor = csvPanda.groupby(['Data', 'UF', 'Municipio']).Valor.sum()
BF_NIS = csvPanda.groupby(['Data', 'UF', 'Municipio']).NIS.nunique()

Depois criei dois Data Frames com estes dados:

DF_Valor = pandas.DataFrame(BF_Valor)
DF_NIS = pandas.DataFrame(BF_NIS)

Por fim os concatenei em um único conjunto de dados:

frames = [DF_Valor, DF_NIS]
DF_BF_Pagamento = pandas.concat(frames, axis=1)

Funcionou. Muito grato a todos!